# WebPage Test Script login failing

Tags: webpagetest

Asking here because the WPT forums are next to useless, am having great difficulty getting WPT to login to my website prior to running a sample.

For some reason the data fields are not being populated, as the screenshot that is returned shows the username and password fields as blank with warning messages that they must be populating [so it appears that the button is being clicked correctly] , but am having a devil of a time figuring out why the two input fields won't populate.

I've tried multiple googsle searcjhes and different coding attempts, and am following the model outlined on the WebPageTest scripting documentation. Have no idea why this is failing or how to determine what the issue is, I'm tracking as closely to the documentation as I believe that I can

```
logData 0
navigate https://www.kroger.com/signin

logData 1
setValue id=SignIn-emailInput UserName
setValue id=SignIn-passwordInput Password
sendClickAndWait id=SignIn-submitButton
```

Login fails to occur, not getting any screenshots indicating why, but believe the input fields are not being populated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Input fields might not be populating as those are not getting selected in the first place to set the value.  Could you please try the below code to select the element and set the value

```js
execAndWait         document.getElementById("SignIn-email").value ="UserName";document.getElementById("SignIn-password").value ="Password";document.getElementById("SignIn-submitButton").click();
```

Comment: Tried the above, no luck there, it doesn't appear to have populated the fields at all :(